# Insert a trailing space into a SQL Server VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, string

I'm trying to insert trailing spaces into a VARCHAR(50) column and the SQL insert seems to be cutting them off. Here's my code:

```
create table #temp (field varchar(10));
insert into #temp select ' ';
select LEN(field) from #temp;
```

Unfortunately, this returns a length of zero, meaning the ' ' was inserted as a ''. I need a blank space to be inserted for this column - any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx), not [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx), because LEN doesn't process spaces.

Take this zero length string, for example:

```
SELECT LEN(' ') AS len, 
       DATALENGTH(' ') AS datalength
```

Results:

```
len   datalength
-----------------
0     1
```

Comment: LEN interprets "Trailing" spaces as a zero length string :)

Comment: @Aamod Thakur: A zero length string doesn't have characters to be trailing ;)

Comment: @Aamod Thakur: Thx, the comment prompted me to re-write the statement so it made more sense.

Answer (score 4):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx:

LEN Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.

Answer (score 1):

You better be aware also that SQL Server follows ANSI/ISO SQL-92 padding the character strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before comparing them. So, you may want to use LIKE predicate for comparisons [1]

[1]
How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626